# How to call an array in a function? PHP

Tags: php, arrays

Global scope allows you to use a variable in a function that was defined outside the function. eg

```
$a=1;
function $test(){
echo $a;
}

//outputs 1
```

but why is it that if I define a variable with an array I cannot use it the same way?

```
$test = array(
0=>'zero', 
1=>'one', 
2=>'two',
3=>'three', 
);

function doesntWork($something){
echo "My favorite number is " . $test[$something]; 
}

//outputs My favorite number is 0
```

How do i pass the array into the function without having to recopy the array into the function itself.

any explanation would be appreciated
thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

script #1 is not correct. neither does it work (function **$**test() {...}), nor does it output "1". and globals ARE bad practice. wrapping them in a class got nothing to do with it. *classes are not a solution for random problems not related to object orientation.*

just pass $a as a parameter:

```
<?php 
  $a=1; 
  function test($foo) { 
    echo 'number ' . $foo; 
  }; 

  test($a);
  // -> "number 1". 
 ?>
```

script #2:

```
<?php
  $test = array(
    0=>'zero', 
    1=>'one', 
    2=>'two',
    3=>'three', 
  );

  function doesntWork($test, $something){
    echo "My favorite number is " . $test[$something]; 
  }

  doesntWork($test, mt_rand(0,3));
?>
```

Comment: ok so you need to redefine the array inside the function?
I asked about classes because ive seen people use public variable with OOP and only define variables once. Im looking for best practises
thanks

Comment: thanks thats exactly what i needed. I ended up doing it with OOP 
    class works{   
    var $a;
    function favNum{echo $this->a;}
    }

Comment: I love this answer's first paragraph!

Comment: The & notation should be used when you want to copy-by-reference instead of copy-by-value in PHP. See http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php for more information.

Answer (score 4):

Your first example should not output 1. The only way to make variables global in a particular function is to use the global keyword like this:

```
function test() {
    global $a;
    echo $a;
}

function doesWork($something) {
    global $test;
    echo "My favorite number is " . $test[$something]; 
}
```

More info here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Comment: i heard using globals all the time is bad practise... should I wrapping them in a class?

Answer (score 0):

PHP doesn't have implicit global scoping; you must use the the [global](http://us.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php) keyword to access "global" variables.

$a outputting 1 is probably due to an intricacy of PHP's dubious handling of variables.